# Passing argument to custom SharePoint list form

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to pass column data as an argument to custom dispform.aspx when view item is clicked ?

For example, if my custom display form name is MyDispform.aspx and when list item is clicked it will open my display form like MyDispform.aspx?user=participant where participant is the column name of the item.

Answer (score 0):

To add a parameter in the page url, it is usually done in the request button click event, like for the list display form, it would be done from the ‘Edit item’ button, however to do this, it needs to custom the ECB menu of the list.

So, based on my understanding, we can try to add a redirect option in your custom display form pageload event, in the event, redirect to the url with specified parameter: MyDisplayForm.aspx?user=participant, in the event we can also get the item information, which can retrieve the parament value. Please have a try.

Thanks